# How can I select and count all <td> elements in a table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table, suppose I click on a button with id `#mybutton`.

For example:

```
<table></table>
<button id="mybutton"></button>
```

I want an alert message with the total number of `<td>` elements and select all `<td>`s in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
$('table').find('td').addClass('selected');
```

Here, with class "selected" you can write your CSS for `select`.

Total number of td in the table:

```
$('table').find('td').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

assuming that your table has id "mytable", you can use

```
$(function(){
    $("#mybutton").on('click', function(){
        alert($("#mytable tr td" ).length);
    })
})
```